# is git reset --hard necessary if merge fails?

Tags: git, bash, sh, git-merge, git-squash

I have the following bash script:

```
git merge --squash -Xtheirs dev -m "squashing" && 
(./test/testsrc/shell/node-c.sh && echo "compiled successfully") || (git reset --hard; exit 1)
```

I have two questions:

1. If the merge fails, do I need to do a git reset to go back to the state before the merge started?
2. Assuming the answer to 1 is "yes", is the above script correct, such that if the node-c.sh script exits with a non-zero code, that git reset --hard will be called and will absolutely exit with code = 1?

I am thinking that when running git merge, the index will always be updated no matter what, so that git reset --hard is always the right thing to do.

As an aside, I am seeing what appear to be some bad Git bug, where the merge doesn't work and produces .js files that get mangled, and often times cannot even by compiled with "$ node -c". Not sure if anyone has seen this before, but I have filed a bug report with Git.

Comment: _I have filed a bug report_: And you have been told essentially that `-Xtheirs` is not a magic bullet, on the contrary, it is just enough rope... ;-)

Comment: @j6t you are absolutely right, that's what the Git folks told me :) Maybe that was you haha. TBH with the failure rate that I have seen -Xtheirs should come with more warnings than those that I have / haven't seen. At least when merging JavaScript code.

Comment: Rather than `git reset --hard` you should use `git merge --abort`. (They wind up doing the same thing for your case but the `merge --abort` is clearer, and more obviously future-proof).  That's for the failed merge part; for the "undo the merge" use `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, as you are doing.

Comment: so I need two commands like so? ... || (git merge --abort && git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD; exit 1)

Comment: @AlexanderMills: as in j6t's answer, you don't *need* it, I'd just recommend it for clarity.  But it would be: `if ! git merge ...; then git merge --abort; elif ! script-test; then git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD; else echo total success whee; fi`.  More or less.

Answer (score 3):

If the merge fails, you're going to be in a conflict state with the branches.  My thought on this is that you're going to be *safer* with using `git merge --abort` rather than `git reset --hard`, since:

- It's clear from the context of the command that you're *only* aborting the merge, and
- Things could crop up in Git's stage that would be lost forever due to a merge failure

You don't want to ever hard-reset a branch without some kind of human/manual intervention; even though what you're resetting would *likely* be safe, you're still playing with plutonium.

---

As to your Git "bug" - I *genuinely* doubt that Git is to blame; it could be a side effect from the intended merge not going as planned and Git requiring that you help it along.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you should actually do this:

```
git merge --squash -Xtheirs dev -m "squashing" && 
(./test/testsrc/shell/node-c.sh && echo "compiled successfully") ||
(git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD; exit 1)
```

When the merge goes through, but `node-c.sh` does not, then you have a merge commit that you do not want. The pseudo-ref `ORIG_HEAD` points to where you were when the most recent merge started: If the merge failed, it is the same as `HEAD`, and when it was successful, it is the same as `HEAD^`.

Comment: Doing one `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` clearly works, but for future-proofing, I'd suggest doing a separate `git merge --abort` if the merge itself fails. (I'm not aware of any plan to *change* how `git reset --hard` works, but given the existence of `git merge --abort`, it seems like some future `git reset` might start giving you a "merge in progress, abort it first if that's what you meant" error.)

Comment: @torek Git has a record for not breaking compatibility. It is, therefore, very unlikely that `git reset --hard` changes behavior, so as not to break scripts like the one under discussion. There may emerge new reset modes, but the existing ones won't changes. BTW, `git merge --abort` is just `git reset --merge` in disguise.

Comment: @j6t: agreed ... but there was Git 2.0. :-)